# OpenCv - iOS MapKit conflict

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, opencv

I am trying to use OpenCv 2.3.1 in my iOS project. But it is conflicting with the iOS MapKit. It's says:

/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/Headers/MKGeometry.h:135: error: 'isinf' was not declared in this scope

The function 'isinf' seems to be implemented in the MapKit as well as in the OpenCv library. If i delete all references to the MapKit, OpenCv is working in my iOS project. But i need both? What can i do?

For including OpenCv in my iOS project i followed this tutorial:
http://aptogo.co.uk/2011/09/opencv-framework-for-ios/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be a known [problem](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/305406-why-won-ios-app-using-mkmapview-compile.html) when using MapKit in an Objective-C++ project. Note that it is nothing to do with OpenCV.

`isinf` is declared as a macro in `math.h` but in an Objective-C++ project, which #includes <cmath>, `isinf` is #undef'd and `std::isinf` is declared instead as a wrapper.

A workaround is to add this line before you #import MKGeometry.h or any of the other MapKit headers:

```
using namespace std;
```

Comment: If you're working in your header file, remove all your MapKit includes and just forward declare the classes & protocols needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not between these libraries, because isinf is declared in the math library (compilation using -lm).

The manpage of isinf tells to include math.h :

```
#include <math.h>
```

What are your system include paths ?